# Insert a number in n place in a list

Tags: haskell

I am using a list and creating many other functions to insert a number into any place in this list. I have done this code but it is giving me some errors: Any help will be much appreciated.

```
list = [1,2,4,5,6,7]
nspace=3
newvalue_n=3
lenlist=length list
calc1= nspace-1
calc2=lenlist-nspace
new_take=take calc1
new_drop=drop calc2
newinsert=new_take ++ newvalue_n ++ new_drop
```

Comment: Does not compiler tell you the very problem? PS: it's not obvious why you need the list length here at all PPS: https://wiki.haskell.org/How_to_work_on_lists#Adding

Answer (score 1):

Not a bad start! When I tried out your file, here were the errors I got. Let's take them one at a time:

```
test.hs:9:11: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[a]’
                  with actual type ‘[a0] -> [a0]’
    • Probable cause: ‘new_take’ is applied to too few arguments
      In the first argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘new_take’
      In the expression: new_take ++ newvalue_n ++ new_drop
      In an equation for ‘newinsert’:
          newinsert = new_take ++ newvalue_n ++ new_drop
    • Relevant bindings include newinsert :: [a] (bound at test.hs:9:1)
```

Well, that's pretty clear. "`new_take` is applied to too few arguments", let's take a look at the definition of `new_take` again:

```
new_take=take calc1
```

Ah, right! You probably wanted this instead:

```
new_take=take calc1 list
```

Next error:

```
test.hs:9:23: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[a]’ with actual type ‘Integer’
    • In the first argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘newvalue_n’
      In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘newvalue_n ++ new_drop’
      In the expression: new_take ++ newvalue_n ++ new_drop
    • Relevant bindings include newinsert :: [a] (bound at test.hs:9:1)
```

Okay, "Couldn't match expected type `[a]` with actual type `Integer` in `newvalue_n` in the expression `newvalue_n ++ new_drop`". Let's remind ourselves of the type of `(++)`, and the definition of `newvalue_n`:

```
(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
newvalue_n=3
```

I have to agree with GHC that `3` doesn't look much like a list. Easy to fix, let's just make it a singleton list:

```
newinsert=new_take ++ [newvalue_n] ++ new_drop
```

And the last one:

```
test.hs:9:37: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[a]’
                  with actual type ‘[a1] -> [a1]’
    • Probable cause: ‘new_drop’ is applied to too few arguments
      In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘new_drop’
      In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘newvalue_n ++ new_drop’
      In the expression: new_take ++ newvalue_n ++ new_drop
    • Relevant bindings include newinsert :: [a] (bound at test.hs:9:1)
```

Just like the first one, you probably wanted:

```
new_drop=drop calc2 list
```

These are the minimal changes needed to get things working. There are many stylistic improvements that can be made; I encourage you to post your code to the [Code Review StackExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) once you get it working to your satisfaction.